# Using the app-debug.apk to install on my device

Tags: android

I have a problem using the app-debug.apk. The program is running correctly on both the device and the emulator  but if I use the app-debug.apk (from PC) to install it on my device (Galaxy Note 4) or another device, the installation complete and once I try to run it, it gives an error "unfortunately, the app has stopped running".

Please note this issue happened after I used poi library to write data to an Excel file. It works correctly, but not if I use app-debug.apk generated on my pc.

Comment: please edit and complete the question

Comment: please add the stacktrace of the app crash to your question and relevant code where the crash occurs.

Comment: That apk file is the same on all devices, so unless you include the actual error message, it's hard to answer

Comment: there is no crash at compile time. I send the app-debug.apk to my phone and I install it without errors. once I run the app I got the message the app has stopped

Comment: I have created a hello world project. I still have the same problem above. what is the configuration that casued the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Problem: You can able to install app with USB cable (adb driver) and works fine. If you copy the app-debug.apk for output directory, the app will not be able to install.

Reason: app-debug file will have all the debugging tools installed in that apk which are used for debugging in Android Studio, and you even notice that the app size is also high than the usual.

Solution: you have to build a signed apk or just build an apk file for that. Go to build menu > build bundles / apk, and then build a apk. After build is finished go to output directory as gone previously for the app-debug.apk and this app-debug.apk file is just recreated without debugger and additional tools that Android Studio wants. Now this file can be installed successfully if you share this file to any device.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this problem. You need to sign the apk from the build menu. You do not need play store signature create your own is enough.